# How to produce a gif/mp4 file from a list of matrices displayed using imshow?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I'm trying to see the evolution of a system in phase space. I have a list of matrices corresponding to each iteration (inside the array "results") and i'm trying to use matplotlib to animate a gif or mp4 file.

I'm omitting the code that leads to the matrices inside results fro brevity but I believe I include everything about the issue itself.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

a = results[0]

def init():
    global im 
    im = plt.imshow(a, cmap=plt.cm.copper,
                interpolation='sinc',
                extent=[-1, 1, -1, 1])
    im.set_data(a)
    return [im]

def animate(i):    
    data = results[i]
    im.set_array(data)
    return [im]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=N, interval=0.1, blit=True)

anim.save('test2.gif', writer='pillow')
plt.show()
```

Currently what I have does produce an output but it is a gif that the image simply fills up to a single color (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW1tJ.gif), which I know for a fact doesn't correspond to the final state of the system because when I use imshow on individual matrices from 'results', I obtain correct results - a pattern in 2D).

Maybe I'm overlapping everything and that's why it turns to a single color? I don't know exactly where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

For these type of tasks I like to use [celluloid](https://github.com/jwkvam/celluloid) (disclaimer: I'm the author). It isn't memory efficient like FuncAnimation is since it uses ArtistAnimation under the hood. That being said here's an example of how you would use it to make an animation from a series of imshow calls. You essentially just call `camera.snap` after each `imshow`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from celluloid import Camera
import numpy as np
from numpy import random as rng

X = np.zeros((100, 100)) + 0.5
fig = plt.figure()
camera = Camera(fig)
for i in range(20):
    plt.imshow(X, interpolation='none', vmin=0, vmax=1)
    camera.snap()
    X += 0.5 * (rng.rand(100, 100) - 0.5)
    X = np.clip(X, 0, 1)
anim = camera.animate()
anim.save('im.mp4')
```

[image]